# Thousands of "Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2r (internal dummy connection)" in my logs

Tags: apache2, apache-log-files

I'm checking the logs of my Apache server, and I've found thousands of records per day like the following one:

`::1 - - [23/Feb/2020:21:56:23 -0500] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2r (internal dummy connection)"`

What is it? Why am I receiving this kind of visit?  Should be worried or not?

Comment: Besides Atarax reply, note that the source IP address is `::1` which is localhost in IPv6 that is this traffic started from the computer itself. It is not a visit coming from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, this is normal.

When the Apache HTTP Server manages its child processes, it needs a way to wake up processes that are listening for new connections. To do this, it sends a simple HTTP request back to itself.

Everything is explained here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/InternalDummyConnection